# Why does PHP call index method in Index class automatically?

Tags: php, indexing

I have the following snipet:

```
<?php

class Index
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}

new Index();
```

It prints out 'Hello' without explicit call of index method. Any change in the name of the class or the method mutes the echo. Why does PHP call index method in Index class automatically? Why does it handle differently when class is renamed to Index2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a old PHP feature where functions with the same name as the class are treated as a constructor. As mentioned in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for constructors:

> For backwards compatibility with PHP 3 and 4, if PHP cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class. Effectively, it means that the only case that would have compatibility issues is if the class had a method named __construct() which was used for different semantics.

and also,

> **Warning** Old style constructors are DEPRECATED in PHP 7.0, and will be removed in a future version. You should always use __construct() in new code.